# Running a code in Perl for a while online - is it possible?

Tags: perl

As the title suggests, I'm looking for an online Perl executor. Yes, I know http://codepad.org/ and http://ideone.com/ can execute Perl scripts online, but I'm looking for something different, so please let me tell you exactly what I'm doing:

I wish to retrieve information from a website say, every 10 or 15 minutes. The information is plain text, and not very big in size. The problem is, that I want to do that for a long period of time, and not always can I leave the computer open for it to run. So what I thought about, is that maybe such a service exists, to which you enter a code, and it starts executing it, while simultaneously printing the current result. I will be given a unique address, and every time I visit it I will see the program's progress.

Does such a thing exists? How can I do what I wish to do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option you have is renting some hosting with a provider that allows you to run a perl script through `cron`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've never heard of cron before. Do you have any good beginner's manual, or should I just read from Google and Wikipedia?

Comment: cron is pretty obscure, and you can find several tutorials on the web. actually, if you are interested in renting a provider, they could have cpanel as a management interface and it offers a simple UI to schedule cron jobs.

Comment: Well, I just realised I could not spend any money on hosting and such things. Perhaps there is a different option?

Comment: I can have hosting from 5$ per month (there are also free hosting providers, but I don't know if they offer perl+cron). Or you can try Google App Engine, which is free up to a certain level of use, but it is python based.

Comment: I'll definitely have a look at both options. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few [cloud providers](http://perlnews.org/2011/05/cloud-support-for-perl/) which support Perl. [dotcloud](https://www.dotcloud.com/pricing/) claims to have a free tier.